# Two tables in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to put two tables on the same graph in matplotlib. The only solution I got so far is to use the `loc` option:

```
T1 = plt.table(cellText=A, loc='left', rowLabels=names1, colLabels=names2,\
               cellColours=plt.cm.coolwarm(normal(A)))
T2 = plt.table(cellText=B, loc='right', rowLabels=names1, colLabels=names2,\
               cellColours=plt.cm.coolwarm(normal(B)))
```

which results in two tables being too far from each other and cut by the graph borders.

Is there a way to manually control the distance between the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify exactly the coordinates of your axes, then you can place each table in a separate axis. See the following example:

```
left, width = 0.1, 0.6
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.8
left_table = left+width+0.1
table_width = 0.15
table_height = width/2.

rect_main = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect_table1 = [left_table, table_height+bottom , table_width, table_height]
rect_table2 = [left_table, bottom, table_width, table_height]

axMain = plt.axes(rect_main)
axTable1 = plt.axes(rect_table1, frameon =False)
axTable2 = plt.axes(rect_table2, frameon =False)
axTable1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axTable2.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axTable1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
axTable2.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

axMain.plot([1,2,3])
axTable1.table(cellText=[[1,1],[2,2]], loc='upper center',
               rowLabels=['row1','row2'], colLabels=['col1','col2'])
axTable2.table(cellText=[[3,3],[4,4]], loc='upper center',
               rowLabels=['row1','row2'], colLabels=['col1','col2'])
```

The output of this looks like:
[image]

Alternatively you can use the subplot feature to arrange the axes for you:

```
axMain = subplot(1,2,1)
axTable1 = subplot(2,2,2, frameon =False)
axTable2 = subplot(2,2,4, frameon =False)
setp(axTable1, xticks=[], yticks=[]) # another way of turning off ticks
setp(axTable2, xticks=[], yticks=[]) # another way of turning off ticks

axMain.plot([1,2,3])
axTable1.table(cellText=[[1,1],[2,2]], loc='upper center',
               rowLabels=['row1','row2'], colLabels=['col1','col2'])
axTable2.table(cellText=[[3,3],[4,4]], loc='upper center',
               rowLabels=['row1','row2'], colLabels=['col1','col2'])
```

The outcome of this is:
[image]